# Spring boot key, value properties file

Tags: spring-boot

Hi Is there a simple way using spring boot to load in a key, value properties file.  I can do it the old way using the Properties class but wanted to check if this can be easily done with spring boot (still new to this)

Thanks,

Example

A = Apple

B = Banana
   etc

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. But, you can use application.properties or application.yml file to specify properties in Spring boot. If you create the project in an IDE using spring.io initializer, application.yml and bootstrap.yml will be automatically created in src/java/resources directory.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  If you place a file named `application.properties` into `src/main/resources/` you can inject its values like so:

**application.properties**

```
foo=bar
```

**Foo.class**

```
@Component
public class Foo {
  @Value("${foo}")
  String foo; //equals 'bar'
  //.......//
}
```

Alternatively you can look up properties programmatically

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class PropertyLookupApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(PropertyLookupApplication.class, args);
        String foo = context.getEnvironment().getProperty("foo"); //equals 'bar'
    }
}
```

**Update**

If you want `application.properties` as a `Map` then you can make sure of Spring's `PropertiesLoaderUtils` utility class:

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("application.properties");
Properties properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
```

That returns a standard `java.util.Properties` object which is a Map.

Comment: Thanks maybe I haven't explained myself properly. . I want to use the external config as a lookup table. So get me the value for "A" or whatever. There could be hundreds of key, values in there so I don't want to be using the @value for each one, if that makes sense.

Comment: You can still do that using application.properties as the lookup table.  Get a handle on the ApplicationContext and try this: context.getEnvironment().getProperty("foo") and that'll return "bar".  Does that solve your problem?

Comment: No. I know I can get a handle on application.properties that isn't the question I am asking. What I am asking is there may be unlimited "foos". I don't want to do @value("${foo}"), @value("${foo100}") etc. I want to know if there is a way to read in all my properties in one go into a map?

Comment: Got it.  I've added an additional option to my answer that I believe does what you need.  It leverages Spring's handy utility class PropertiesLoaderUtils.

Comment: Perfect example. Exactly looking to load the properties to a Map. But can this be done using simple annotations like @ConfigurationProperties. Thanks.